# is it async task is compulsory to implement whenever wanted to post data to server from android c to perform login

Tags: android, database, authentication

Here i want to get data from user input and post it to server in order to login succesful, im using url connection method and wondering how to implement async task in my code.

```
  public void onClick(View v) {


        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.loginbtn:



                try {

                    String link = "192.168.0.81/android/login.php";
                    username = uname.getText().toString();
                    password = upass.getText().toString();
                    String str = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
                    Log.d(TAG, str);

                    String data = URLEncoder.encode("str", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                            URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8");
                    Log.d("ENCODED", data);

                    //connecting sql
                    URL url = new URL(link);
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

                    wr.write(data);
                    wr.flush();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;

                    // read server response
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                        sb.toString();
                        break;
                    }

//                    return sb.toString();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.getMessage();
//                      return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                }



                break;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not compulsory, you can change the thread policy and make network calls from the UI thread itself, but if you do that you can feel that lag in your application due to network calls. If you want your application to be responsive, then you've to use either thread or Asynctask! Learn about OkHttp, it is an networking  library.. It's very simple than URLConnection,  [check it here!](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)